# Trying to compare an array value to a variable in OpenCV (Python)

Tags: python

I'm completely new to Python

I am trying to write a script that can output an array of numbers representing the colors of individual pixels in a set of images.

What I am trying to output is an array of numbers (0 through 7) each number representing one of 8 colors in the image. There would be 1020 arrays each 49 numbers in length (the image is 30x34 and there are 49 frames)

An example of an array I need is:
`5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,5,6,7,6,6,6,6,5,6,6,7,5,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5`

Currently I am using (image[y, x]) to get the RGB value of the pixels which is a good start but I don't know how to continue.

How can I compare the printed value of (image[y, x]) to a variable that could be used to represent 0 through 7?
From there I could generate the string/array that I need.

Is there a better way to approach this?

Here is my current code. It generates the RGB values of every pixel of every frame.

````py
y = 0
x = 0
f = 1

image = cv2.imread('r' + str(f) + '.png')

cg = (image[y, x])
print (cg)
#print (x)
#print (y)
#print (f)
while f < 49:
    x += 1
    if x == 33:
        x = 0
        y += 1
    if y == 29:
        y = 0
        f += 1
    if f == 49 or f > 49:
        break
    image = cv2.imread('r' + str(f) + '.png')
    cg = (image[y, x])
    if out != cg:
        out = cg
    print (out)
    #print (x)
    #print (y)
    #print (f)```
````

Comment: Your question and title could be edited to read a little more clearly. From what I am understanding, you are really just asking about how to map a 3-color 24-bit RGB value to a single 3-bit value (0-7), correct? The rest seems to just be structural code which I think you have a handle on.

Comment: @Smolakian I'm not entirely sure I understand you, I am trying to convert the string I get from (image[y, x]) which usually outputs as something like [000 000 000] into a single digit that is used to represent it.
I am not very familiar with all of this, how should I edit my post to be clearer?
Thanks

Comment: First, you should not get a "string" from that pixel. You should get the values as an array of 3 numbers([R,G,B]). Then you can perform arithmetic or comparisons on them just like any other array of numbers. (see my answer below) In your post you should also should specify what format this RGB image is in. 3-bit color, 8-bit color, etc...That will tell us how many bits represent each color value otherwise it's impossible to figure out the math.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might be asking about how to map color spaces. That can be a little tricky in terms of figuring out exactly how to map 16,777,215 possible colors down to 8. You can easily google different methods to do that.

However, if you are just looking for 8 specific colors, you could structure this in many different ways. One simple and easy to read method would be to create a list of RGB values for each color you are looking for and do a list comparison on each one.

```py
color0 = [255,0,0] 
color1 = [0,255,0]
...
if image[x,y] == color0:
     print("color0")
     #add 0 to your array
elif image[x,y] == color1:
     print("color1")
     #add 1 to your array
```